# Strong intermitent sewage smell in bathroom, possible broken underfloor pipe

Tags: bathroom, smell

I am experiencing a strong smell of "sewage" in my bathroom (and sometime outside the side of the bungalow next to bathroom). This smell is intermittent and NOT linked to use of toilet for #2's.

### To complicate things the bathroom has a 2 - 3 feet void underneath the tiled floor.  The floor is not tiled underneath the bath.

My 11 year old bath has a "coating" of something on the base of it (some sort of insulation?), could this be causing a smell, as when I take the panel off there is a smell?

Comment: Check that your vent stack isn't plugged.

Comment: Can you provide a picture?

Answer (score 1):

Although your question is not detailed or specific enough to provide definitive answers, you should **do** these things:

- Check the void space that you mentioned for signs of a sewage leak
- Have a plumber run a camera down your branch and main sewer lines to check the integrity
- Check your vent lines to ensure they are not plugged or restricted
- Check for a drain that is not frequently used (like a hidden floor drain) and run some water down it to establish a seal in the trap if necessary)

Consider this:

- It is not uncommon for drain flow(s) from another appurtenance to cause a siphon action in a tub or sink drain, resulting in sewer gases/odors entering the room. This is caused by inadequate venting and there are methods to abate it, call a plumber.